# Is "a band which I'm a huge fan of" correct?

Tags: word-choice

Is "a band which I'm a huge fan of" correct?

Or is "which" out of place there? I know I can simply say "a band I'm a huge fan of". I just don't know whether the version containing "which" is also correct. I guess not.

Answer (score 1):

> A band which I'm a huge fan of

Is correct and grammatical.

Comment: Thank you, Peter.

Comment: Yes, it is acceptable and used. But it should be pointed out that it is formed from: A band of which I am a huge fan.

Answer (score 1):

You can say any of these:

> a band I'm a huge fan of

> a band which I'm a huge fan of

> a band that I'm a huge fan of

you can even say:

> A band who I'm a huge fan of

because the band is presumably made up of people.